# Mockito: Stub method with complex object as a parameter

Tags: java, parameters, mockito, stub

Maybe this is a newbie question, but can't find the answer.

I need to stub a method with Mockito. If the method has "simple" arguments, then I can do it. For example, a find method with two parameters, car color and number of doors:

```java
 when(carFinderMock.find(eq(Color.RED),anyInt())).thenReturn(Car1);
 when(carFinderMock.find(eq(Color.BLUE),anyInt())).thenReturn(Car2);
 when(carFinderMock.find(eq(Color.GREEN), eq(5))).thenReturn(Car3);
```

The problem is that the find argument is a complex object.

```java
 mappingFilter = new MappingFilter();
 mappingFilter.setColor(eq(Color.RED));
 mappingFilter.setDoorNumber(anyInt());
 when(carFinderMock.find(mappingFilter)).thenReturn(Car1);
```

This code does not work. The error is "Invalid use of argument matchers! 1 matchers expected, 2 recorded".

Can't modify the "find" method, it needs to be a MappingFilter parameter.

I suppose that I have to do "something" to indicate Mockito that when the mappingFilter.getColor is RED, and mappingFilter.getDoorNumber is any, then it has to return Car1 (and the same for the other two sentences). 
But how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a Hamcrest matcher, as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3):

```
when(carFinderMock.find(argThat(isRed()))).thenReturn(car1);
```

where `isRed()` is defined as

```
private Matcher<MappingFilter> isRed() {
    return new BaseMatcher<MappingFilter>() {
        // TODO implement abstract methods. matches() should check that the filter is RED.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since **2.1.0** Mockito has its own matcher mechanism build on top of `org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher` interface. This allows to avoid using Hamcrest. Usage is almost of same as with Hamcrest. Keep in mind that `ArgumentMatcher` is a functional interface and implementation of a matched can be expressed as a lambda expression.

```
private ArgumentMatcher<SomeObject> isYellow() {
    return argument -> argument.isYellow();
}
```

and then

```
when(mock.someMethod(argThat(isYellow()).thenReturn("Hurray");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly implement `equals()` method of your *MappingFilter*. In *equals()* you should only compare color and not *doorNumber* .

In simplest form, it should look like this -

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    MappingFilter other = (MappingFilter) obj;
    return other.getColor() == this.getColor();
}
```

Also, you should form your MappingFilter simply as below instead of using any matcher such as eq

```
 mappingFilter = new MappingFilter();
 mappingFilter.setColor(Color.RED);
 mappingFilter.setDoorNumber(10); //Any integer
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Is it possible to do it without implementing the equals method? For example, the filter has 20 fields and I only want to test when color and door number have the specified value, and in another piece of code when the color and car type have the specified value (without comparing the door number), etc.

Comment: Well, alternatively, as pointed by @JB Nizet, that seems to be the way to do it.